# Calculating the degrees of freedom

Tags: anova, interaction, experiment-design, degrees-of-freedom

Hi I wonder if there is a standard way to calculate the degrees of freedom. I am having a hard time understanding why these sums of squares has only one degree of freedom.

1. In one-way ANOVA (one factor of $a$ levels), the sum of squares for a contrast $\sum_{i=1}^ac_i\tau_i$ for $\sum_{i=1}^ac_i = 0$ has one degree of freedom.
   $SS_C = \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^ac_i\bar{y}_{i\cdot}\right)^2}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^ac_i^2}$
2. In two-way ANOVA (factor A of $a$ levels and factor B of $b$ levels) and the model is $y_{ij} = \mu + \tau_i + \beta_j + \epsilon_{ij}$, $i = 1, 2, ..., a$, $j=1, 2, ..., b$. Suppose that there is only a single replicate and we assume $(\tau\beta)_{ij} = \gamma\tau_i\beta_j$ for a constant $\gamma$. The Tukey test for significance of interaction says that the following
   $SS_N = \frac{\left[\sum_{i=1}^a\sum_{j=1}^by_{ij}y_{i\cdot}y_{\cdot j} - y_{\cdot\cdot}\left(SS_A + SS_B + \frac{y_{\cdot\cdot}^2}{ab}\right)\right]^2}{abSS_ASS_B}$
   has one degree of freedom. There is a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.2883.pdf) talking about this test.

I am very confused about these cases and I wonder if there is any standard way that we can calculate the degrees of freedom.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer [here](http://www.jerrydallal.com/LHSP/dof.htm). The degrees of freedom are "the rank of a quadratic form".

Answer (score 5):

Every time you write the "equals" sign `=`, you spend one degree of freedom (unless you can derive this equal sign from others supplied before).

You wrote down one contrast (+1, -1, 0, 0)? That's one degree of freedom.

You wrote down two contrasts (+1, -1, 0, 0) and (-0.5, 0, -0.5, +1)? That's two degrees of freedom.

You wrote down three contrasts (+1, -1, 0, 0), (+1, 0, -1, 0) and (0, +1, -1, 0)? Well you can deduce the third one by subtracting the first one from the second one:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}+1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} +1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ +1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

So there are only **two** equalities you are testing, so that's two degrees of freedom.

You wrote down that you think $\gamma = 0$? That's one degree of freedom.

Comment: This is incorrect because it ignores the possibility of linear dependence among the equations.

Comment: You are right, @whuber -- I added a paragraph in the middle to that effect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I wonder why the two sums of squares have 1 degree of freedom. I am still not so clear what you mean by the equal sign, do you mean it is the "equal to zero"? Could you please recommend some source about this as well?

Comment: C R Rao's LSI is a classic https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Statistical-Inference-its-Applications/dp/0471218758

Comment: @StasK for $SS_E$ of one-way anova for example, with your explanation, why does it have $n-p$ degrees of freedom?